# Converting code listings from mediawiki to latex using pandoc

Tags: latex, mediawiki, syntax-highlighting, pandoc

Is there an easy way to say pandoc converter I wish to replace all my source codes in mediawiki article convert to an lstlisting environment on its Latex output?

At this moment, all my `<source lang="c"> some code... </source>` environments are converted into something like this

```
\begin{Shaded}\begin{Highlighting}[]
\NormalTok{         some code \textless{}\textless{} }\DecValTok{1}\NormalTok{ \CommentTok{// set... \end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}
```

Not only the code is completely unreadable but also my Latex distribution is not able to translate the code and is missing probably some packages.

I wish to have simply `\begin{lstlisting} some code \end{lstlisting}` at the output with no additional changes to the code itself.

And I don't speak Haskell, believing there should be an easier way...

Comment: Did you try with the `--listings` option https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--listings? Can you show us a [mre] including how you call pandoc?

Comment: Thanks for this comment. Unfortunately, I didn't notice the --listings option.

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to solve the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was very simple. There is a `--listings` command line option solving this problem as Sam Carter pointed out.